# How do I utilise Javascript merging?

Tags: javascript, magento2.2.7

To be clear, this is not a post about Javascript Bundling. This is about Javascript Merging.

So, I'm in Production Mode and I'm starting to look at the optimisation of Javascript Merging. My benchmarks are as follows:

- Javascript Bundling = **Off** (226 js files load)
- Javascript Bundling = **On** (223 js files load)

I honestly expected this difference to be much more significant. [Magento Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/js-bundling.html) says to just turn it on. But clearly, there's another level to it than that.

What am I missing to fully utilise the Javascript Merging feature?

Answer (score 0):

After lots of tutorials I could manage to make this work by running:

`bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

`bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 1`

`bin/magento config:set dev/js/minify_files 1`

`bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 1`

then I've deleted manually everything except `.htaccess` from `pub/static` and

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`